How to test ,using jest, an express app built with ts if I have a specific ts compiler config?
any idea how to test express app with this ts config?
I tried jest, but I get errors because of wrong extension, that's .js
However, you have to use .js inside of ts files since module is set to node16.
I suppose, I could try to fix it by specifying different values for ts compiler options, but I want use the recommended ones from ts guidelines.
{
"$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
"display": "Node 20",
"_version": "20.1.0",
"extends": "@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2023"],
    "module": "node16",
    "target": "es2022",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node16"
}

I tried jest but got errors
